# Flexbox not displaying full width of page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use Flexbox to create my own grid.  I don't want to use Bootstrap or any other framework, so please don't link any of them.

In my `flex-container`, I want to display two sections which are both 100% of the page's width.  So one section should be positioned on top of the other.  Instead, each section is being given 50% of the page's width even when I **explicitly** defined 100%.  I have no idea why this is happening.  The browser's developer tools don't lead me to any conclusions either.

I reconstructed the problem in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jq6k72o0/).  I get the expected result if, let's say, I define one section to be 7/12 the page's width and the other section to be 5/12 the page's width.

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-12">
        <h4>Title</h4>    
        <p class="flex-2">Content</p>
        <p class="flex-2">Content</p>
        <p class="flex-2">Content</p>
        <p class="flex-2">Content</p>
        <p class="flex-2">Content</p>
        <p class="flex-2">Content</p>
        <p class="flex-2">Content</p>
        <p class="flex-2">Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-12">
        <h4>Title 2</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: btw - if you have 2 divs with 100% width, one after the other, you don't need flexbox, as this is the natural behavior.

Comment: @OriDrori Yeah that's a good point.  In this example it was only necessary for the nested elements.  In my Angular app there is a lot more nesting though, and nearly no static content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to tell the container to permit wrapping as the default is `nowrap`.

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jq6k72o0/2/)

Comment: Ya this makes more sense than my answer because you are making a grid system

Answer (score 2):

You can use also use flex-direction column:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```